# Search Outlook Global Address List Asynchronously

Tags: vb.net, active-directory, ldap, vsto, outlook-addin

I want to;

- Search the Global Address List of MS Outlook
- Using an input, *filterStr*
- To retrieve **all** items **asynchronously** that match a criteria satisfying

  - Contact first name starts with *filterStr* or contact last name starts with **filterStr**
- Display the contacts as they become available in some sort of list

I am developing a MS Outlook add-in with Visual Studio 2017 using VB.net. (c# code examples are wellcome). I need this add-in to be able to search contacts like MS Skype for Business does, through its "Find Someone" field of "RICHEDIT60W"

I have tried the following so far;

- Use "RICHEDIT60W" of MS Skype for Business (the search field) in my form

  - Could not find documentation
- Use the "RichEdit20WPT" of MS Outlook (the "TO:" field in new e-mail compose)

  - Could not find documentation
- Get the "Global Address List" through `Session.GetGlobalAddressList`

  - Succeeded, but looping through more than 50k items is too slow
- Use the `System.DirectorySearcher`

  - This does not always work. When I'm connected to my corporate network through cable, I can create the object. When I'm connected through my home wireless, I get the error: "specified domain does not exist or could not be contacted"
  - I did try using a `DirectoryEntry` object initialized with;
  - `name.surname.corporation.com` where my e-mail address is name.surname@corporation.com, this time I get an "*unspecified error*"
  - I tried using ADODB to connect as given in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ad/example-code-for-searching-for-users#visual-basic-example
  - This also gives me an error on line 42 (`root = GetObject("LDAP://rootDSE"`)

QUESTION: How can I do any of the following;

- Get `DirectorySearcher` to  work
- Get ADODB method to work
- Use the existing RichEdit controls of either Outlook or Skype for Business

?

Comment: Do you just need to let the user pick someone from the GAL? This could be what you need: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.selectnamesdialog

Comment: I need to make a custom control, to be displayed as a field in a table. When the user is going to enter multiple rows of items, I'm hoping to refrain from a dialog popping up for each line. I also need to be able to dynamically display matching contacts as the user is typing.

Answer (score 0):

On the low (Extended MAPI - C++ or Delphi only) level, you would need to apply `PR_ANR` MAPI restriction: that is what Outlook uses when it resolves a name and displays the list of ambiguous matches. You can run that code on a separate thread, but it won't return matches one at a time - you will get the whole set back.

If Extended MAPI is not an option, you can use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) and its `RDOSession.AddressBook`.[GAL.ResolveNamesEx](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAddressList.htm) method:

```
set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
set AdrrEntries = Session.AddressBook.GAL.ResolveNameEx("John")
Debug.Print AdrrEntries.Count & " names were returned by ResolveNameEx:"
Debug.Print "------------"
for each AE in AdrrEntries
    Debug.Print AE.Name
next
Debug.Print "------------"
```

Comment: I was hoping to get your attention Dmitry, thanks. Unfortunately, I'm not allowed to use Redemption, we have a general trend to avoid using 3rd party libraries and the "works around limitations imposed by the Outlook Security Patch" bit in the description played a role in this decision.

Comment: Can you please point me to any documentation on how to use the Extended MAPI? Can I use the exposed functions from vb.net, like for the functions in user32.dll?

Comment: "works around limitations imposed by the Outlook Security Patch" does not mean "hacks around the limitation.." - it uses the documented and fully supported Extended MAPI API, which is the native API used by Outlook itself, but only accessible in C++ or Delphi. VB.Net cannot do Extended MAPI - there used to be a third-party library directly exposing Extended MAPI to .Net languages (MAPI33), but it is not longer available.

Comment: Many thanks Dmitry, I will try out Redemption in one of my own projects and forward your kind explanation. In the meantime, I found a solution which appears to work for me. Would you have any comments about that?

Comment: I would not do that - see my comment.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this;

- Getting the GAL itself and the `AddressEntries` is fast enough, no problem there
- I'm looping through the `AddressEntries` only once, during initialization and getting *only* the `Name`properties of each to a `List(Of String)`, which takes around 3 seconds
- When I need to search for an entry, I'm using Linq to query the list with `IndexOf` function, which takes about 150ms max to get all matches, and the items of the list are immediately accessible

This suited my needs because
 - It works through my home network and even when I don't have a connection (I assume Outlook is cacheing the GAL)
 - Querying using Linq is fast enough to facilitate searching as the user types

Comment: Do not do this. never loop through all items in GAL (or an Outlook folder) - some GAL containers contains hundreds of thousands of entries. Even with smaller GAL containers, your code will break in the online (as opposed to cached) mode. Let the server do the work.